# PwSh RegEx capture Version information - omit (surrounding) x(32|64|86) & 32|64(-)Bit

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm pulling my hair, to RegEx-tract the bare version information from some filenames.
e.g. "1.2.3.4"

Let's assume, I have the following Filenames:

```
VendorSetup-x64-1.23.4.exe
VendorSetup-1-2-3-4.exe
Vendor Setup 1.23.456Update.exe
SoftwareName-1.2.34.5-x64.msi
SoftwareName-1.2.3.4-64bit.msi
SoftwareName-64-Bit-1.2.3.4.msi
VendorName_SoftwareName_64_1.2.3_Setup.exe
```

(And I know there are still some filenames out there, that have "x32" as well as "x86" in them, so I've added them to the title)

First of all, I replaced the `_`'s & `-`'s by `.`'s which I'd like to avoid in general, but haven't found a cleverer approach and to be honest - only works well if there's no other "digit"-information in the String for example like the 2nd Filename.

I then tried to extract the Version information using Regex like

```
-replace '^(?:\D+)?(\d+((\.\d+){1,4})?)(?:.*)?', '$1'
```

Which lacks the ability to omit "x64", "64Bit", "64-Bit" or any variation of that generally.

Additionally, I played around with RegExes like

```
 -replace '^(?:[xX]*\d{2})?(?:\D+)?(\d+((\.\d+){1,4})?)(?:.*)?$', '$1'
```

to try to omit a leading "x64" or "64", but with no success (most probably because of the replacement from `-`'s to `.`'s.

And before it gets even worse, I'd like to ask if there's anybody who could help me or lead me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the expected output for the strings you listed? Can you have `SoftwareName-1-1980-64-Bit-1.2.3.4.msi` as input?

Comment: @Wiktor: Like I tried to show with the example: "1.2.3.4". Just a bare and nice version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be done using a single pattern, but by splitting it up into two separate patterns and let PowerShell do some of the work, the overall solution can be much easier.

**Pattern 1** matches version numbers that are separated by `.` (dot):

```text
(?<=[\s_-])\d+(?:\.\d+){1,3}
```

**Pattern 2** matches version numbers that are separated by `-` (dash):

```text
(?<=[\s_-])\d+(?:-\d+){1,3}
```

The patterns start with `(?<=[\s_-])` which is a positive lookbehind assertion that makes sure that the version is separated by space, underscore or dash on the left side, without including these in the captured value. This prevents sub string 64-1 from the first sample to match as a version.

Detailed explanations of the pattern can be found at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/cqZsMz/1).

**Powershell code:**

```sh
# Create an array of sample filenames
$names = @'
VendorSetup-2022-05-x64-1.23.4.exe
VendorSetup-x64-1.23.4-2022-05.exe
VendorSetup-1-2-3-4.exe
VendorSetup_2022-05_1-2-3-4.exe
Vendor Setup 1.23.456Update.exe
SoftwareName-1.2.34.5-x64.msi
SoftwareName-1.2.3.4-64bit.msi
SoftwareName-64-Bit-1.2.3.4.msi
VendorName_SoftwareName_64_1.2.3_Setup.exe
NoVersion.exe
'@ -split '\r?\n'

# Array of RegEx patterns in order of precedence.
$versionPatterns = '(?<=[\s_-])\d+(?:\.\d+){1,3}',  # 2..4 numbers separated by '.'
                   '(?<=[\s_-])\d+(?:-\d+){1,3}'    # 2..4 numbers separated by '-'

foreach( $name in $names ) {

    $version = $versionPatterns.
        ForEach{ [regex]::Match( $name, $_, 'RightToLeft' ).Value }.   # Apply each pattern from right to left of string.
        Where({ $_ }, 'First').                                        # Get first matching pattern (non-empty value).
        ForEach{ $_ -replace '\D+', '.' }[0]                           # Normalize the number separator and get single string.

    # Output custom object for nice table formatting
    [PSCustomObject]@{ Name = $name; Version = $version }
}
```

**Output:**

```text
Name                                       Version 
----                                       ------- 
VendorSetup-2022-05-x64-1.23.4.exe         1.23.4  
VendorSetup-x64-1.23.4-2022-05.exe         1.23.4  
VendorSetup-1-2-3-4.exe                    1.2.3.4 
VendorSetup_2022-05_1-2-3-4.exe            1.2.3.4 
Vendor Setup 1.23.456Update.exe            1.23.456
SoftwareName-1.2.34.5-x64.msi              1.2.34.5
SoftwareName-1.2.3.4-64bit.msi             1.2.3.4 
SoftwareName-64-Bit-1.2.3.4.msi            1.2.3.4 
VendorName_SoftwareName_64_1.2.3_Setup.exe 1.2.3   
NoVersion.exe
```

**Explanation of the Powershell code:**

- To **resolve ambiguities** when a filename has multiple matches of the patterns, we use the following rules:

  - Version with `.` separator is preferred over version with `-` separator. We simply apply the patterns in this order and stop when the first pattern matches.
  - Rightmost version is preferred (by passing the [`RightToLeft`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-options#right-to-left-mode) flag to `[regex]::Match()`).
- `.ForEach` and `.Where` are [PowerShell intrinsic methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_intrinsic_members?view=powershell-7.2#foreach-and-where). They are basically faster variants of the `ForEach-Object` and `Where-Object` cmdlets.
- The index `[0]` operator after the last `.ForEach` is required because `.ForEach` and `.Where` always return arrays, even if there is only a single value, contrary to the behaviour cmdlets.

Comment: thanks a lot for your effort. Unfortunately your latest update doesn't work for me. I think it's because I'm on PwSh 5.1 and don't have that "-Stable" switch for Sort-Object. But I really like the idea and solution of making it more robust!

Comment: @BaBa There you have it, robust version that works under PS 5.1 too.

Comment: Works very nice! Thank you so much! Only thing I've changed is the last replacement from ```-replace '-', '.'``` to ```-replace '\D+', '.'```. Do you see any problems with doing so?

Comment: @BaBa Great idea! So you can change the version patterns without having to change the `-replace` arguments in the future.